Which elements are eligible to be members of a css Grid? Can child elements be used, ignoring their parents?
I'm learning about CSS-Grid and CSS-Flex.  I wasn't able to discover if a CSS Grid can be built with elements (IDs/selectors/classes) that are children, alongside parents.
I want to totally disregard the class "div#foo" and only use its children, #foo_alice and #foo_bob.   I would like them to be peers in a CSS grid with #logo and #bar.
Is this possible?
HTML Code:
    <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="logo">
          <p>LOGO</p>
        </div>
        <div id="foo">
          <ul id="foo_alice">
            <li>alice1</li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="foo_bob">
            <li>bob1</li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="foo_carl">
            <li>carl1</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="bar">
          <p>BAR</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    ...

Desired CSS:
#wrapper {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-areas:
    "logo alice carl"
    "logo bob   bar";

  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

#logo {
  grid-area: logo;
}

#foo_bob {
  grid-area: bob;
}

#foo_alice {
  grid-area: alice;
}

#foo_carl {
  grid-area: carl;
}

#bar {
  grid-area: bar;
}

In this example, all of the #foo_* elements were rendered in the same box, instead of where they were placed by grid-template-areas.
Are the elements required to be peers, in order to be used in Grid?  How about in Flex?
Why don't I just do a flex on #foo?
I'd like to mix foo_carl and #bar in the same grid, as you can see in column 3.
Why don't I just change the HTML?
I'm limited to a CSS only solution and want to understand if CSS can handle this.

#foo {
  display: contents;
}

display: contents basically removes elements, but leaves thier children.
